# How to release memory of the fragment after I coding getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()? I remove it but widgets instantiated as well

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a question about how to release memory of the fragment after I coding getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()?

## QUESTION 1

There are Fragment A and B.
Define them like this:

```
Fragment A = new Fragment();
Fragment B = new Fragment();
```

change A to B and add A into the back stack.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack("A")
            .replace(R.id.frame_content, A)
            .commit();
```

But when I call onBackPress(call the popBackStack), something will wrong.The memory of B won't be released and it's even more. The last Allocated memory in Android Monitor is 14.66MB.But when I pop, the memory changed to 14.72MB. I want to know how to fix this?

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

## QUESTION 2

There are Fragment A and B.

A ListView in A and when I click item, A will replaced by B and add A into the back stack(just like the QUESTION 1).

Fragment B own a ScrollView. When I scroll it, eg.I scroll to position A.
Then I popBackStack() to return A. 
When I click a different item in A, I enter B again but the ScrollView is in position A as well. It should be in the start position.
I guess that because the scrollview didn't recycle.
How to fix it?

Please. Any anwses will be appreciated! It took me a long time. Make me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Memory in android, well actually java is freed by the garbage collector when an object is no longer referenced. The backstack is something android holds onto as you navigate from one activity or fragment in this case to the next so if the user navigates to the previous screen it does not have to start from scratch to render it. If you want you could A=null or B=null. In low memory situations a priority algorithm decides who lives and who dies, yes I know sounds primitive but would you prefer just crashing? Java has a sandbox and does not allow pointers and other low level things like destructors(), free() malloc() for security reasons, those terrorist are everywhere. I suggest you google "java garbage collector"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I misunderstand the Android Monitor. I thought that it occurs memory leak if the Allocated Memory didn't go down after popping. It should click the the yellow car in the toolbar of Memory.

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help. I don't have a yellow car but I do remember maybe it was a plugin you could click the icon and force garbage collection